# HP Laserjet Professional P1566 USB printer isn't printing

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I have installed the printer and it says its all fine. When I go to print something it says printing and then finished etc. but doesnt actually print at all. No idea what to do and if you need extra info let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Based from what or how your question is written I would suggest the following:

1. Go to the Ubuntu Software Center
2. Search for "hplip", or click here: [hplip](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/hplip) [image: Install hplip]
3. Install HPLIP (might already be installed)
4. Connect the printer (USB)
5. Run HPSETUP (Alt+F2 & enter "hp-setup")
6. Follow the wizard to setup your printer

Comment: this seems fine; the P1566 is a senior device: 7yrs old and doesn't get a mention on the hplip supported printers website; one assumes though that it will support it; I thought hplip was a core feature of Ubuntu installs;  so unlikely to need to install it; and `hp-setup` is the command to get the printer config going